# Connecting の adjectives

Tags: grammar

So when connecting い adjectives you go from い to くて Like:

> おもしろい 楽しい -> おもしろくて楽しいです。= interesting and fun

And with な adjectives you add で Like:

> きれいな やさしい -> きれいでやさしいです = pretty and kind

So what do you do with a の adjective? I want to say 'a sunny and warm place' using はれ and あたたかい but はれ is a の adjective so I don't know how to connect it so I was wondering what to do in this case.

(I know I can just say 'あたたかくてはれの所' but I was just wondering how you would say it the other way round.)

Comment: "*I know I can just say 'あたたかくてはれの所'*" - based on what rule exactly?

Comment: I think the answer is just using "で”. For example "はれですずしい”. I can write an proper answer if this was what you were looking for.

Answer (score 2):

はれの あたたかい -> はれていてあたたかい
This is the answer of your question but I don't know general rule of の adjectives.
I'll show you some examples.

はれの あたたかい -> はれていてあたたかい
あめの あたたかい -> あめがふっていてあたたかい
くもりの あたたかい -> くもっていてあたたかい